# How to sign in and update phone number at once with the same verification id sent from firebase in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

I've been working on Firebase phone number authentication in flutter. The authentications works fine as it should but I want to update the phone number of the user once the verification is successful as well so on other user can use the number again.

The feature has been implemented but the only problem is that when the updatePhoneNumber method is called, it throws exception that the credentials has been expired because it has already been used to authenticate the user.

My only question is that how can I authenticate the user as well update user's phone number in the firebase's user object at the same time with only a single OTP?

Thanks, here's the code.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pinput.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:udhar_book/services/auth/auth_service.dart';

class OTPVerificationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phone;

  const OTPVerificationScreen({super.key, required this.phone});

  @override
  State<OTPVerificationScreen> createState() => _OTPVerificationScreen();
}

class _OTPVerificationScreen extends State<OTPVerificationScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String? _verificationCode;
  final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();

  final int _duration = 120;

  final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
    width: 56,
    height: 56,
    textStyle: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20,
      color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 60, 87, 1),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    _verifyPhone();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('OTP Verification'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Verify +92-${widget.phone}',
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 26),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Pinput(
              length: 6,
              defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
              controller: _pinPutController,
              pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.fade,
              onSubmitted: (pin) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _authenticate,
            child: const Text('Verify'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _verifyPhone() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+92${widget.phone}',
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        final user = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).user;

        await user?.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
        print('User phone number saved(inside-method): ${user?.phoneNumber}');
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: (String? verficationID, int? resendToken) {
        setState(() {
          _verificationCode = verficationID;
        });
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
        setState(() {
          _verificationCode = verificationID;
        });
      },
      timeout: Duration(seconds: _duration),
    );
  }

  _authenticate() async {
    try {
      final credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: _verificationCode!,
        smsCode: _pinPutController.text.trim(),
      );

      final user =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credentials);

      if (user.user != null) {
        // throws expired token exception
        user.user!.updatePhoneNumber(credentials);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString())),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried working on either of these features with otp and both works fine but with single OTP only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Signing the user in with the new phone number should already result in their account being associated with *only* that number. As far as I know, the additional call to `updatePhoneNumber` is superfluous.

Comment: It should but as soon as I call for user's phone number on home or profile screen, it displays null, shows only for those whose updatePhoneNumber method is been called actually.

Comment: Hmm... that seems wrong, so might be better to investigate. Did you already `reload` the user ([docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html)) to check if that sets their phone number? It should not be necessary, but... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Actually I didn't but a different approach did worked out for me thought. However when I saw that my approach worked because after working through, I was able to see user's emails and phones both at the same time in the firebase console which wasnt' happening in the first case, still thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @AliWajdan!  --- Could you post an answer below with the code of what you did, so that others can benefit from it going forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself, but not in the way I expected though, I just called the updatePhoneNumber method with the provided credentials, if it works then it simply means that the phone number is valid and is not in use by any other user within the app, so just update the number using the code below and then sign in.

Only condition for the app was that the user was first logged in with email password, the main code is in else part

```
final credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
  verificationId: _verificationCode!,
  smsCode: _pinPutController.text.trim(),
);

final provider = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);

if (provider.user == null) {
  final user = await provider.signInWithCredential(credential);
  String? name = user.user?.displayName;
  if (user.user?.displayName == null) {
    name = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(GetNameScreen.routeName);
    await provider.writeUser(user.user!, name);
  }
} else {
  // Code to update the phone number
  print('Updating Phone Num...');
  await provider.user!.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
  await Provider.of<FireStoreService>(context, listen: false)
      .writePhoneDoc(provider.user!.uid, '+92${widget.map['phone']}');
  if (widget.map['pop']) await provider.signOut();
}
```